# How to transfer input value from one input to another with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to type in to an input and have that value show up in another input here is what I have been working with. So basically input from `userreplymessage` goes to input `userreplydisplay`.

**html**

```
<form id="userreply">
    <select id="usernames">
        <option value="">Users</option>
        <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
        <option value="Jeff">Jeff</option>
        <option value="Amy">Amy</option>
        <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
    </select>
    <input id="userreplymessage" type="text" />
    <input id="userreplydisplay" type="text" />
</form>​
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function update() {
        $('#userreplydisplay').text('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#userreplymessage').val());
    }

    $('#userreplymessage').keyup(update);
    $('#usernames').change(update);
});​
```

Comment: What is your question?  What isn't working?

Comment: when i type into the `userreplymessage` input nothing shows up in the  `userreplydisplay` input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your input elements, userreplydisplay and userreplymessage are input textboxes. The setter and the getter are both `.val()`. You're using the getter correctly, but you're using the wrong setter.

```
$('#userreplydisplay').val('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' +
    $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#userreplymessage').val());
```

Change "text" to "val" and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks i just have one issue it works fine on jsfiddle but when i try it on my website nothing works when i start typing

Comment: Well, the code looks fine from what I can tell, and you've confirmed that yourself in a test environment. It's logical to assume you have a conflict on your site. I'd start by putting some console.debug log statements in your update function and use Chrome Dev Tools to see if it's being called when you type.  Then step backwards with more log statements until you find the needle in the haystack. Also, are there any JS errors? If so, you might want to start by fixing them or wrapping them with try/catch blocks.

Comment: console said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Answer (score 3):

This Line uses text() :

```
$('#userreplydisplay').text('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#userreplymessage').val());
```

It should be val()

```
$('#userreplydisplay').val('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#userreplymessage').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val` method to set the value of the input, not the `text` method:

```
$('#userreplydisplay').val('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#userreplymessage').val());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rxsg/